# CSS pseudo before automatic numbering

Tags: css

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 background-image: url("background.jpg");
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #808080;
}
p {
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #808080;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
hr {
 border: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #808080;
}
.pass {
 counter-reset:paragraph;
}
.pass p {
 padding-left: 50px;
}
.pass p:before {
 counter-increment:paragraph;
 content:counter(paragraph);
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 text-align: left;
 width:50px;
}
a:link {
 color: #B2AB19;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
}
a:hover {
 color: inherent;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #B2AB19;
}
a:active {
 color: inherent;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
}
a:visited {
 color: #B2AB19;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
}
#container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#lcolumn {
 float: left;
 max-width: 250px;
 border: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#rcolumn {
 margin-left: 250px;
 border: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#footer {
 clear: both;
 width: 90%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body lang="zh-hk">
<div id="container">
  <div id="nav">
    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
  <div id="header">
    <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260>
  </div>
  <div id="lcolumn">
    <p><a href="index.html">Chiayi</a></p>
    <p><a href="index.html">From the Airports</a></p>
    <p><a href="index.html">Places</a></p>
    <p><a href="index.html">Food and Drinks</a></p>
    <p><a href="index.html">Bike Trips</a></p>
  </div>
  <div id="rcolumn">
    <h1>Reaching Chiayi City from the Airports by Public Transport</h1>
    <p>Which interational airport will you arrive at?</p>
    <p>&#8226; <a href="#tpe">Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE)</a></p>
    <p>&#8226; <a href="#rmq">Taichung Airport (RMQ)</a></p>
    <p>&#8226; <a href="#khh">Kaohsiung International Airport (KHH)</a></p>
    <hr>
    <h2 id="tpe">Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE)</h2>
    <p>Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE) is located in the north of Taiwan and the furthest from Chiayi.</p>
    <div class="pass">
      <p>Take bus 1627 running from Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport to Zhongli Service Area. Get off at Zhongli Service Area for the transfer to the next bus. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=37" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=2986" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus</a>; <a href="http://www.taoyuan-airport.com/english/Buses/#e0871f13-0119-445f-8a41-f9a6913cc00e" target="_blank">Airport transportation guide</a></p>
      <p>Take bus 1618 running from Taipei Bus Station to Chiayi Bus Station. Some buses do not stop at Linkou and Zhonggang Bus Station, but this does not matter to passengers going to Chiayi. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=23" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=4321" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 1</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=9237" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 2</a></p>
    </div>
      <p>The total trip time is about 4 hours. The tickets of the buses are sold together as a package. You need to buy them from the operator Ubus in advance at the bus counter or online. Pay attention at the promotion.
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    &#169;2016
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I learned about how to use pseudo before for automatic numbering from this post:
[right-align CSS before: numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990761/right-align-css-before-numbers)

What I like about the method:

1. no space before the number at all
2. I can make space of a fixed distance between the left of the number
   and the beginning of the text
3. The whole paragraph is indented, not just the first line

I try to apply the method but the numbers go too left. Please see:
jsfiddle.net/milktheox/fe9o9cen/

I have tried different methods, for example:
http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/numbering-headingshtml.html
But they can't fulfill my 3 targets. Please advise. Thanks so much!

Comment: I couldn't make it in a stack snippet. I'm sorry.

Comment: Where is the stack snippet button? http://imgur.com/a/y13v0

Comment: Oh thanks. It's different from the one in the sample page. Have I made it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `position: relative` on the parent to contain the `position: absolute` numbers. Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fe9o9cen/1/.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sen: I don't ask for thanks. Just up-votes and answer acceptance! ;) But, you're welcome.